# MySQL count rows where column value is same and select them where count is greater than 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I am dealing with an issue that I have to backtrack as the entire project is already in production and system has been used for a while.

I need to backtrack all the data with the following parametars.

`Select * from table where bundle = 5 and count(bundle) >= 3`

This will be a joined table so technically I need count of bundles greater than 2 with same transaction.

eg

```
id | transaction | bundle
-------------------------
1  | 123         | 5
3  | 234         | 15
12 | 1111        | 5
13 | 1111        | 15
17 | 1111        | 5
18 | 1111        | 5
```

My code so far

```
select * from table_i as ti
right join table_r as tr
on tr.id = ti.t_id
where ti.type_id = x and ti.bundle = 5 and ti.online = 1 and count(ti.bundle) >=5
```

Thanks

## EDIT REAL CODE:

```
SELECT ti.*, tr.*
FROM ticket_items AS ti
INNER join transactions as tr
ON tr.id = ti.trans_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tis.trans_id, COUNT(tis.bundle) AS bundle_count
    FROM ticket_items as tis
    INNER join transactions as trs
    ON trs.id = tis.trans_id
    WHERE tis.type_id = 2
    AND tis.bundle = 5 
    AND tis.online = 1 
    HAVING bundle_count > 2
) sub0
ON sub0.trans_id = ti.trans_id
WHERE ti.type_id = 2
AND ti.bundle = 5 
AND ti.online = 1
```

Result:
`1328   1   1   766 2   5   25  1   1   2015-10-26 20:26:41 2015-10-27 00:00:02 0   766 1   0   John Doe    123-123-1234        NULL    email@email.com NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   164 Cedar Square    NULL    123 rrt city    province country    125 2015-10-26 20:26:41 2015-10-26 20:26:41 125.00  0.00    0.00    0.00    0   1`

Table ticket_items:

```
id | lot | system | trans_id | type | bundle | price | print | online | date                | update              | void
1    1     2        1          1      1        100     1       0        2015-10-01 23:30:12   2015-10-03 18:49:25   0
2    1     2        1          2      15       50      1       0        2015-10-01 23:30:12   2015-10-03 16:48:15   0
3    1     3        2          1      1        100     1       0        2015-10-02 00:13:57   2015-10-02 00:22:17   1
4    1     3        2          2      15       50      1       0        2015-10-02 00:13:57   2015-10-02 00:19:17   1
```

Table transactions:

```
id | lot_id | cust | first | last| number |||||||
1  | 1      | 23   | john  | doe | 123
```

Comment: If you simply query the records where bundle is 5, then you can easily see, if you have got more than 2, or 3, or 5 (all 3 numbers are in your question). So, I do not really understand what you are trying to achive with this.

Comment: Issue is I need to look trough 2000 records and I don't want to wast time on that, I would rather query and get only the ones that were affected by the system error. I need to look at every transaction and if error has occurred I need to fix it manually. If I need to do this on over 2000 records it  is very ineffective. But if I can end up with 700 that were affected than it will save me some time.

Comment: Error is only on bundle 5s.. System has issued 3 - (5s) instead of 1-15

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what your are talking about. Can you pls clarify in your post what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: With that test data I wouldn't expect any records to be output as nothing on ticket_items has online = 1

Comment: Not in the sample however there is over 10,000 records and ball park 4500 have 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find transactions where there are more than 3 with that transaction code for a bundle of 5 and with online = 1, and then bring back all the rows from the 2 tables for that transaction with a bundle of 5 and with online = 1

If so, a sub query to get the transactions with a count of more than 3 and then join that back against the 2 tables:-

```
SELECT ti.*, tr.*
FROM table_i AS ti
INNER join table_r as tr
ON tr.id = ti.t_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tis.transaction, COUNT(tis.bundle) AS bundle_count
    FROM table_i as tis
    INNER join table_r as trs
    ON trs.id = tis.t_id
    WHERE tis.type_id = x 
    AND tis.bundle = 5 
    AND tis.online = 1 
    GROUP BY tis.transaction
    HAVING bundle_count >= 3
) sub0
ON sub0.transaction = ti.transaction
WHERE ti.type_id = x 
AND ti.bundle = 5 
AND ti.online = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, however this also returns only 1 record.. and yes your idea is correct of what I am trying to achieve here.. However this only returns 1 record

Comment: Can you post a bit of test data for the 2 tables and the output for that test data please. Currently I cannot do anything to know whether the issue is with the SQL, or with the choice of rows in the 2 WHERE clauses.

Comment: I missed out the GROUP BY line which would have caused problems.

Comment: Took me few minutes but yeah group by was missing !

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by the wording of your question, but try this:

```
SELECT ti.id, ti.transaction, count(ti.bundle)
FROM table_i as ti
JOIN table_r as tr
  ON tr.id = ti.id
WHERE ti.type_id = x 
  AND ti.bundle = 5 
  AND ti.online = 1 
  AND count(ti.bundle) >=5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `having`. Something like this:

```
select ti.*, count(ti.bundle) from table_i as ti
right join table_r as tr
on tr.id = ti.t_id
where ti.type_id = x and ti.bundle = 5 and ti.online = 1
group by ti.bundle
having count(ti.bundle) >=5; /* or >= 3 depending on which you're using now*/
```

Comment: This returns only 1 record, I already tried this... I just can't wrap my head around it. I need to return records that have 3 or more 5 bundles..